# Unexpected error when adding webpart to modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I've been having trouble adding a custom web part to my modern page. I was able to add the web part to a legacy site, but I don't have the same luck with modern sites. In the legacy site it works normally.

This is on sharepoint online.

This error appears in the place of the web part:

```
An unexpected error has occurred.
TECHNICAL DETAILS


Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
Correlation ID: 28e1389f-d083-2000-3dc2-806f4c872efa
```

[image: The error message]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate little more about - what type of webpart you are trying to add?

Here is a Microsoft details document about the webpart name in classic and modern experience :

[Classic and modern web part experiences](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/classic-and-modern-web-part-experiences-3fdae6c3-8fc1-49ab-8708-8c104b882e64)

Notes :

- The webpart name in classic and modern experience is not same. For example, in classic "Content editor webpart" but the same in modern is "Text Webpart" . There are so many like this, please read the above msdn table.

Comment: The webpart basically just displays a list of all lists on the sharepoint site. It's an SPFx webpart.